# EmberJS not respecting rootURL directive

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to get Embers to work with a server context root but I it keeps trying to reference the root context path when I attempt the following.  Unfortunately when I do perform a do the store.find the url it tries to access doesn't include my context root.

I have tried a a few slightly different things to no avail.  I'm sure this isn't a edge case as many people must have to act within context paths.

Thank in advance,
Eric

```
window.Dashboard = Ember.Application.create({
    rootElement: '#ember-app',
    LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
});

Dashboard.Router.reopen({rootURL: "/dlmp/proteomics/"});

Models.registerModels(Dashboard);

Dashboard.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('completed');
    this.resource('ordered');
});

Dashboard.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect: function() {
        // this redirects / to /dashboard
        this.transitionTo('completed'); //TODO: load from local storage the users setting
    }
});

Dashboard.CompletedRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, sample) {
        controller.set('model', sample);
    },

    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render('orderTable');
    },

    model: function(params){
        return this.store.find('sample', {count: 25, orderBy: 'completeDate'})
    }
});

Dashboard.OrderedRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, sample) {
        controller.set('model', sample);
    },

    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render('orderTable');
    },

    model: function(params){
        return this.store.find('sample', {count: 25, orderBy: 'orderDate'})
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to change the following and it seems to work.

```
Dashboard.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    namespace: 'dlmp/proteomics/'
});
```